# this.props.history.push('/') is getting executed even if there is an error

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Even if there is an error in fetching data from firebase my router navigates to root component

```
axios.post('/orders.json', order)
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({ loading: false });
            this.props.history.push('/');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            //console.log(err)
            this.setState({ loading: false });
        });
```

Comment: How do you know the promise gets rejected? What happens when you put logs in both the `.then` and `.catch` callbacks?

Comment: If i am intentionally adding error by changing '/orders.json' to '/orders' even then only .then block gets executed and and in console it prints undefined

Comment: It's possible that the API returns a success http status even if there's no response content. Have you checked what the response status code is? Is this using your own API? Maybe you're not returning the right failure status codes for nonexistent paths?

Comment: I am using axios package

Comment: I can see that. My question is about the API you're sending requests to.

Comment: I am sending requests to firebase realtime database. Sorry if didn't answer correctly I'm a beginner.